# SAP call RFC in Android

Tags: android, saprfc, sup

Anyone know of an example that demonstrates how to connect to a service using SAP RFC in Android?

Answer (score 3):

Native RFC most certainly won't be possible because you'd need a closed-source native library for this that is not available on Android platforms. You'll have to use the web service wrappers.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a web service and call that web service through SOAP.